# Laravel 5.1 - Manipulating Multiple Databases

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a situation where by I need to manipulate two databases that  have exactly the same structure.

I don't really want to do the following method in all of my model's methods:

```
$data = [
    'username' => 'john.doe'
];

DB::connection('mysql1')->table('users')->update($data);
DB::connection('mysql2')->table('users')->update($data);
```

Is there an API in Laravel 5.1 to insert, update and delete from multiple databases? For example, calling update in the user model would update both databases.

```
$this->update(['username' => 'john.doe']);
```

Comment: No, you have to do it explicitly by specifying databases. The default one will be used without explicite indication.

Answer (score 0):

Create some sort of bridge class that accepts a query, duplicates it and then processes it in both databases with the '->connection('dbname')'. Create a new facade for it like DB2:: and run them through there.

There's no native functionality as it's not a typical use-case to manipulate 2 identical DBs at the same time from 1 app :)